# Looking for docusign rest api exception handling assistance

Tags: api, rest, exception, docusignapi

I am using Rest API Embedded Signing.  Part of the Cert process is handling exceptions properly.  I see that the returnURL event param can return "exception". How do i discover what the exception was so i can handle properly and display "Human, friendly" messages? : )  Is there any preferred method of testing/validating my exception handling code against possible exceptions, like specific test urls that force exception returns?
MTIA

Answer (score -1):

So in terms of Certification, the DocuSign Certifications department requires that you include contact info on any error message you display, letting the user know who they can contact to help resolve the error.  And the contact info can NOT be DocuSign contact info, it needs to be specific to your organization or some other 3rd party, otherwise you won't pass certification.

In terms of possible errors, the RESTAPI guide has a page that lists possible errors the system can throw:

[REST API Errors List](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/Error%20Code/Error%20Codes%20and%20Associated%20Messages.htm)

It's a relatively large list, but since your question is with regards to Embedded Signing, you just need to handle errors related to embedded recipients (also known as "captive" recipients).  Doing a search for the term "captive" yields the following errors from the list, which should all be possible through the Embedded Signing workflow -

- CAPTIVE_CARBON_COPY_RECIPIENT_NOT_SUPPORTED
- CAPTIVE_IN_PERSON_SIGNER_RECIPIENT_NOT_SUPPORTED
- INVALID_CAPTIVE_RECIPIENT_OPERATION
- RECIPIENT_NOT_CAPTIVE

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How do i determine which of these errors has occurred when i receive "?event=exception" as a URL parameter in the returnURL page?

Comment: Sorry it's been hard to find more info on this issue.  I think in terms of certification what I mentioned before is the most relevant - your app just needs to handle potential exceptions gracefully, and you need to include non-DocuSign contact info when reached.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your environment is like, but if you're using .NET maybe this will help.  What I did was set an out parameter on the embedded signing method I got from docusign so that a bool was returned, true when returned through the exception block, false if it returned the iframe token url.

```
//Console.WriteLine("Embeded View Result --> " + responseText);
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            failure = false;
            return url;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    //Console.WriteLine(text);
                    failure = true;
                    return text;
                }
```

With the exception you also get the error text that has the error code and error message.  In my view I tested if the failure bool was true, if it was I knew that the text returned was the error text and not the URL token to load in an iFrame.  After determining the text was the error I parsed it to display the code, then the message, then some custom text asking the user to email our helpdesk system with the error text displayed.

Here's what I used to test for failure and display iFrame or parse the error text in my ASPX view:

```
<%if (Model.APIfail)
      { %>
        <p><strong>It appears there was an error connecting with DocuSign API.</strong></p>
        <p>Error Code: <br /><%: Model.urlResponse.Substring(Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("<errorCode>") + 11, Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("</errorCode>") - (Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("<errorCode>") + 11)) %></p>
        <p>Error Message: <br /><%: Model.urlResponse.Substring(Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("<message>") + 9, Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("</message>") - (Model.urlResponse.IndexOf("<message>") + 9)) %></p>
        <p>Please submit error code and error message to the MAAX Spas helpdesk at <a href="mailto:helpdesk@maaxspas.com?Subject=DocuSign%20API%20Failure%20<%: Html.Encode(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) %>" target="_top">helpdesk@maaxspas.com</a>.<br />Thank you.</p>
    <% } else { %>
        <iframe src="<%: Model.urlResponse %>" width="100%" height="1000" ></iframe>
    <% } %>
```

Of course I haven't gotten certified either yet so take this with a grain of salt as I could be rejected for whatever reason using this method.

Hope this is useful in some way.

Comment: You misunderstand. The request is not for general API call errors, but for when a captive form is signed and Docusign then redirects the user back to the returnUrl, but has the status parameter set to indicate an exception.